# UITableViewCell Transfer from input on other view controller Runtime Breakpoint (lldb)

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, breakpoints, lldb

I'm trying to set up a to do list that takes the task from the second view controller and adds it in a table view on the first one. I've been following a popular tutorial, the support on the comments is limited. Had a good look at other tutorials and posts for that matter but none use the same form and, being only fairly new to swift can't find the link they have.

The error is with the UIButton on the second view controller, it triggers the movement of the text to the first view which is a table which stores the text.

The error happens in-app and is a breakpoint at this line.

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
```

The error message is only lldb and couldn't see anything helpful in the bt

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x23e9e, 0x00000001044ed5e3 ToDo Task`ToDo_Task.FirstViewController.tableView (tableView=0x00007f9721851600, indexPath=0xc000000000000016, self=0x00007f9720f6e7f0)(ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell + 35 at FirstViewController.swift:27, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 3.1 4.1
  * frame #0: 0x00000001044ed5e3 ToDo Task`ToDo_Task.FirstViewController.tableView (tableView=0x00007f9721851600, indexPath=0xc000000000000016, self=0x00007f9720f6e7f0)(ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell + 35 at FirstViewController.swift:27
    frame #1: 0x00000001044ee2af ToDo Task`@objc ToDo_Task.FirstViewController.tableView (ToDo_Task.FirstViewController)(ObjectiveC.UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath : ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath) -> ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell + 79 at FirstViewController.swift:0
    frame #2: 0x00000001050594b3 UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
    frame #3: 0x0000000105038fb1 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
    frame #4: 0x000000010504ee3c UIKit`-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    frame #5: 0x0000000104fdb973 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    frame #6: 0x0000000108ed9de8 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    frame #7: 0x0000000108ecea0e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
    frame #8: 0x0000000108ece87e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
    frame #9: 0x0000000108e3c63e QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
    frame #10: 0x0000000108e3d74a QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 390
    frame #11: 0x0000000104f5f14d UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2035
    frame #12: 0x000000010460c551 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #13: 0x000000010460241d CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    frame #14: 0x0000000104601a54 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 868
    frame #15: 0x0000000104601486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    frame #16: 0x00000001087cd9f0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #17: 0x0000000104f62420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
    frame #18: 0x00000001044ebf1e ToDo Task`top_level_code + 78 at AppDelegate.swift:12
    frame #19: 0x00000001044ebf5a ToDo Task`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
    frame #20: 0x00000001069f4145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

The error is in this function

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    cell.textLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = taskMgr.tasks[indexPath.row].desc

    return cell
}
```

And it uses taskMgr which is in a new cocoa file

```
var taskMgr :TaskManager = TaskManager()

struct task{
    var name = "un-named"
    var desc = "un-described"


}
class TaskManager: NSObject {
    var tasks = [task]()

    func addTask (name: String, desc: String){
        tasks.append(task(name: name,desc: desc))


    }

}
```

Not sure if there is an easy fix for these things, as I said, I'm new to swift and didn't want to ask anything too simple but can't do anything in my knowledge to get through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead of creating an instance of `UITableViewCell` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Test",
            forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Also register your UITableViewCell before using it in `viewDidLoad` if you are using a custom `UITableViewCell`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerClass(TestCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestCell")
}
```

Comment: Cheers, had to tweak it in and polish it but got it done. Thanks a lot.